# in django app even if migration folders files are deleted this error exists 'relation "blog_no_of_views" does not exist'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I was using SQLite in the beginning but now I tried switching to PostgreSQL and tried executing makemigrations command, now I am getting below error

```
 (youngmindsenv) E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds>python manage.py makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_no_of_views" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."views_count", "blog_no_of_views"."username" FROM "blog_no_o...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\funct
ional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolv
ers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\funct
ional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolv
ers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126
, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds\young_minds\urls.py", line 27, in <modu
le>
    response = common_info()
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds\blog\views.py", line 35, in common_info

    print(popular_post)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\q
uery.py", line 248, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\q
uery.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\q
uery.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\q
uery.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=
self.chunk_size)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\s
ql\compiler.py", line 1064, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py
", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_no_of_views" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."views_count", "blog_no_of_views"."username" FROM "blog_no_o...
                                                         ^
```

as suggested in answers by others as I don't worry about losing the data, so I deleted the tables and database as well, I have deleted the migration folder files and created **init**.py inside it and tried makemigrations command but still, I am getting the above error,

I am so confused from where is it getting that error since there is no files in the apps migrations folder

it gives an error in all of below commands as well

```
./manage.py clear_cache
./manage.py clean_pyc
./manage.py reset_schema
./manage.py reset_db
```

database settings for PostgreSQL.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Test@123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'social_django',
    "django_extensions",
    #'sslserver'
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Post,Comment,Category,No_Of_Views,carousel_images_messages,about_page_details
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def home(request):

    context = {"posts":Post.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context)
def feedback_email(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        send_mail(('username ({})  '.format(request.user.username))+"[ "+request.POST.get('subject')+" ]",
        request.POST.get('feedback_content'),'alphayoungminds@gmail.com',
        ['alphayoungminds@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(request,f'Thank you for taking your time out! Your Feeback is very important to us!')
    return redirect("about")
def common_info():

    #for category with count
    categories = Post.objects.values('category__category').order_by('category').annotate(the_count=Count('category'))

    # for popular post with views
    popular_post = No_Of_Views.objects.all().order_by('-views_count')[:5]
    print(popular_post)
    popular_post_list = []
    for post in popular_post:
        single_post = Post.objects.get(pk=post.post)
        popular_post_list.append(single_post)


    result = {"categories":categories,"popular_post":popular_post_list}
    return result


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 8

    def get_queryset(self):

        post_list = []

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')

        if search :

            posts_all = Post.objects.filter(Q(author__username__icontains=search) |
            Q(title__icontains=search) |
            Q(content__icontains=search)).order_by("-date_posted")
            for post in posts_all:
                try:
                    views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                    views = views.views_count
                    post.views = views
                except:
                    views = 0
                post_list.append(post)
        else:
            posts_all = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date_posted")
            for post in posts_all:  #this line is giving same error again
                try:
                    views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                    views = views.views_count
                    post.views = views
                except:
                    views = 0
                post_list.append(post)

        return post_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]
        context['popular_posts'] =  response["popular_post"]
        context['carousels'] = carousel_images_messages.objects.all()
        context['title'] = "Young Minds"
        '''print(response["categories"])
        print(response["popular_post"])'''


        return context

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 8



    def get_queryset(self):

            post_list = []

            search = self.request.GET.get('search')

            if search :

                posts_all = Post.objects.filter(Q(author__username__icontains=search) |
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(content__icontains=search),Q(author__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))).order_by("-date_posted")
                for post in posts_all:
                    try:
                        views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                        views = views.views_count
                        post.views = views
                    except:
                        views = 0
                    post_list.append(post)
            else:
                posts_all = Post.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username')).order_by("-date_posted")

                for post in posts_all:
                    try:
                        views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                        views = views.views_count
                        post.views = views
                    except:
                        views = 0
                    post_list.append(post)

            return post_list


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.kwargs.get('username')
        context['title'] = user.title() +"'s Posts"
        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]
        context['popular_posts'] =  response["popular_post"]
        context['user_name'] = self.kwargs.get('username')
        return context



class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/category_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 8


    def get_queryset(self):

        post_list = []

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')

        if search :

            posts_all = Post.objects.filter(Q(author__username__icontains=search) |
            Q(title__icontains=search) |
            Q(content__icontains=search),Q(category__category__iexact=self.kwargs.get('category'))).order_by("-date_posted")
            for post in posts_all:
                try:
                    views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                    views = views.views_count
                    post.views = views
                except:
                    views = 0
                post_list.append(post)
        else:
            posts_all = Post.objects.filter(category__category__iexact=self.kwargs.get('category')).order_by("-date_posted")

            for post in posts_all:
                try:
                    views = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=post.pk)
                    views = views.views_count
                    post.views = views
                except:
                    views = 0
                post_list.append(post)

        return post_list
        '''category = self.kwargs.get('category')
        print(category)
        print(Post.objects.filter(category=category).order_by("-date_posted"))
        return Post.objects.filter(category=category).order_by("-date_posted")'''

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['selected_category'] =  self.kwargs.get('category')
        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]
        context['popular_posts'] =  response["popular_post"]
        context['title'] = 'Category-'+ self.kwargs.get('category')
        return context


'''class ActiveUserPostDetailView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_all_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author__username=self.request.user).order_by("-date_posted")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # no of views

        ## ends here
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]
        context['popular_posts'] =  response["popular_post"]

        return context'''


class AboutListView(ListView):
    model = about_page_details
    template_name = 'blog/about.html'
    context_object_name = 'about_makers'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]

        context['title'] = 'About Page'
        return context





class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # no of views

        no_of_views = No_Of_Views.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs.get('pk')).exists()

        #RealEstateListing.objects.filter(slug_url=slug).exists()
        if no_of_views:

            no_of_views_count = No_Of_Views.objects.get(post=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            print(no_of_views_count.username)
            print(self.request.user)
            print(no_of_views_count.views_count)

            if no_of_views_count.username != self.request.user.username:
                no_of_views_save = int(no_of_views_count.views_count) + 1
                no_of_views_count.views_count =  no_of_views_save
                no_of_views_count.save()
            else:
                no_of_views_save = no_of_views_count.views_count

        else:
            post_title = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            print(post_title.title)


            no_of_views_save =  0
            no_of_views_for_post =  No_Of_Views(post=self.kwargs.get('pk'),post_title=post_title.title,username=post_title.author,views_count=no_of_views_save)
            no_of_views_for_post.save()


        ## ends here
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = Post.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post=post[0],reply=None).order_by("-id")

        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        is_liked = False

        if post[0].likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True



        similar_post_pk = Post.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")
        similar_post_pk = similar_post_pk[0]

        similar_post  = Post.objects.filter(category__category__iexact=similar_post_pk.category.category).exclude(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")[:3]
        if len(similar_post) == 0:
            similar_post  = Post.objects.all().exclude(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")[:3]
        context['is_liked'] = is_liked
        context['similar_posts'] = similar_post

        context['views'] = int(no_of_views_save)
        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]
        context['popular_posts'] =  response["popular_post"]
        title = (post[0]).title
        context['title'] = title
        #context['total_likes'] = post.total_likes()

        return context
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by("-date_posted")
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content = comment_form.cleaned_data["content"]
            reply_id = self.request.POST.get("comment_id")
            comment_qs = None
            if reply_id:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
            comment_form = Comment.objects.create(post=post[0],user=self.request.user,content=content, reply=comment_qs)
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect("post-detail",pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))



class PostLikeListView():
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/likes_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]

        context['title'] = 'About Page'
        return context

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["title","category","content","thumbnail"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        response = common_info()
        context['categories'] =  response["categories"]

        context['title'] = 'Create Blog'
        return context

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["title","content","image1","image2","image3"]
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = "/"
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def like_post(request):
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print("\ninside like view\n")
        print("\n in {} \n".format(request.POST.get('id')))
        post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get("id"))

        is_liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            print("\ninside like\n")
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            is_liked = False
        else:
            print("\ninside dislike\n")
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            is_liked = True
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post,reply=None).order_by("-id")
        context = {
        "post":post,
        "is_liked":is_liked,
        "comment": comments
        }
        #return redirect("post-detail",pk=request.POST.get("post_id"))
        print("\ngetting in ajax\n")
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("\ninside ajax\n")
            html = render_to_string('blog/likes_section.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({"form":html})
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        pass

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

please help me I am so troubled by this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change the database settings correctly? Perhaps it is still somehow referring to the sqlite database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ya i have updated the database settings. in question

Comment: Perhaps you might want to remove the `*.pyc` files yourself, so `find -iname '*.pyc' -delete` (including the virtual environment)

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace? I suspect you have querysets being executed when your app is being loaded

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do i find the '*.pyc' in virtual environment, how do i know which '*.pyc' file needs to be deleted . m confused already.sorry

Comment: @IainShelvington i have updated the view.py in questions. do you want anything more that will help you understand my problem

Comment: @young_minds1 is that the full stacktrace?

Comment: @IainShelvington i have included full error report ,sorry i didnt know what stacktrace meant

Comment: Line 27 in "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds\young_minds\urls.py" is calling `response = common_info()`. You should not be calling any functions that execute querysets in your urls

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you so very much.it worked, i was going to go bald due to over scratching my head, you saved me. it worked, thanks a million. i will always keep this in mind from now on

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, I got this kind of errors yesterday. What I did was just comment some code lines which are using tables from `models.py`. For an example your `views.py` accessing some values from table which are in `models.py`. Isn't it? For now just comment those lines from `views.py`.

Now you you don't have `migrations` file in your app directory. Create `migrations` directory with `__init__.py` file. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` command. If you get any errors, please comment to this answer and I'll update it accordingly. After the `migrations` don't run `migrate` command.

Then run `python manage.py showmigrations` command and you'll see something like this.

[image]

What does that `[X]` mean? It check your migrations with the database tables. If the changes which are related to your migrations already in the database it display `[X]` icon before your migration file name, if it doesn't will display `[ ]` this kind of icon. If you see it, then run `python manage.py migrate` command, otherwise run `python manage.py migrate --fake` command. This is how I solved my problem. Always checking with `showmigrations` and get an idea about it before run `migrate` command. If you see `[ ]`, but  it already in the database, then run `python manage.py migrate --fake <app_name> <migration_file_name>`. Then run `python manage.py migrate`. This is little bit confusing, I know but this should be work.

Now uncomment what you were commented.

Comment: hi one of the comment by  Iain Shelvington helped me to solve it. it was due to my silly mistake i have called a function in urls.py , removing it helped me to solve the problem, thanks for taking time out to answer ! appreciate it !

Comment: You're welcome @young_minds1 , just check the comments, he is right. But I got the same error and I did these changes to solve it. Let me know if you are getting any other errors.

Comment: now i am getting error when i am trying to createsuperuser i have commented in views.py where i am facing error . the line "posts_all = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date_posted")
            for post in posts_all:" is giving the error " django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "blog_post"."image2", "blog_post"."image3" FROM "blog_post..." i will be very grateful if you can help me

Comment: I think still you have some problems with migration @young_minds1, did you try my above answer? Do you see any `[  ]` icon when you run `showmigrations` command?

Comment: i solved this on local system,now i am trying to deploy in heroku ,migrate is working fine but when trying to createsuperuser ,it is giving error in signals.py file "File "/app/users/signals.py", line 9, in create_profile
  Profile.objects.create(user=instance) " which i have updated in the question

Comment: I think you are following [How to Create Django Signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) tutorial and it should be work.